# Does anyone know what command in cmd causes this output?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

So I'm doing homework and I came across this picture:

[image: Command line output]

The question just asked what command would cause this.

Sorry if this isn't the place for these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is output from the [traceroute command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute).

Type `tracert google.com` into a DOS prompt.